# Confluence Rest API - Return Pages sorted by position

Tags: cql, wiki, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I am using the Confluence API to retrieve children of a parent. The following API call returns the children of a Page with Id 123456, ordered by last modified date.

```
rest/api/content/search?cql=parent=123456+order+by+last-modified
```

However, I would like to have the results sorted by the position of the children. Any ideas?

Comment: It will almost certainly be necessary to know the specific Confluence REST API version. I've worked with version 3.3.1 and a bit of v5.9.6. In v3.3.1 "../content/<pageId>?expand=children" may be what you want. However, "position of the children" is ambiguous. "Position" in what sense / relative to?

Comment: The position in which I have reordered my pages or the position in which I see the children under the parents. I think I am using Version 6, but not sure.

Comment: I haven't used the version v6 RESET API. However, if memory serves, the example I in my earlier comment did as you desire for v3.x, i.e. provides the pages in the order seen "under the parent". Best luck - wish I had your definitive answer.

Comment: It appears that using this API call returns the results by position.  rest/api/content/PARENTID/child?expand=page

Comment: Glad you figured it out - and shared. I am no expert on this site's use but I believe you should enter and accept your answer :) In part so we can close it out so it doesn't continue to show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following API call, addresses the above question. It returns children for a parent based on their position. The answer was addressed in the Confluence community.

```
rest/api/content/PARENTID/child?expand=page
```